# how to verify DB hive already exists

Tags: postgresql, linux

by expect script we create the database hive and some other commands

in case we run the expect script again on the machine that hive already created

then we get - **ERROR hive already exists**

so how to verify **database hive already** created ?

And by this verification we can escape the **expect script**

```
# su - postgres
 Last login: Sun Aug 13 11:12:03 UTC 2017 on pts/0
 -bash-4.2$ psql
 psql (9.2.13)
 Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE hive;
ERROR:  database "hive" already exists
```

my expect script: ( from my bash script )

```
set timeout -1

#exec the scripts

spawn timeout 60 ssh root@IP
expect "#"
spawn su - postgres
expect "$"
send "psql\n"
expect "=#"
send "CREATE DATABASE hive;\n"
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Using `SELECT datname from pg_database where datistemplate is false order by 1;` to check exists db. For shell script, please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549270/check-if-database-exists-in-postgresql-using-shell

Answer (score -3):

you can use `IF EXISTS` clause:

```
create database if exists hive;
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your contribution/participation. However, the community does expect a certain quality in the questions and answers posted. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I write a good answer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) (Help Centre)_ In the section **Answer the question** there is a short sentence which reads: _Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better._ Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/214872/edit) your answer and add some details. Thank you.